# Forgotten Username and Password in Ubuntu 7

Tags: password-recovery, username

Hi I found an old laptop that I would love to find out what is still on it. I hadn't updated an ubuntu that was installed in 2009. Any Idea on how to change a forgotten username and password from the login screen?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. You will need to reset your password. First restart your PC, wait for the GRUB menu to appear(similar to this)[image: grub menu]

Now, from the list, select the **Advanced option for Ubuntu** and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>
There will be two options, select the option to go to **recovery** mode.

Now you will be present with different options of recovery mode. Now you have to  choose **Root Drop into root shell prompt**

You need to have write access to the `root` partition. By default, it has only read-only access using the command

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

Now, list all the users that are present in the system

```
ls /home
```

Use the command

```
passwd username
```

where `username` is the user from the list whose password is to be reset. `passwd` is used to set a password for the user.

It will prompt for a new password. Enter the new password twice (there will be no visual feedback i.e: you won't see any characters on the screen)

Then exit the root shell prompt by typing `exit`

When you exit, you will be back to the recovery mode menu. Select **resume** for normal boot option.